# Can FluentMigrator output one SQL file per migration?

Tags: c#, .net, database-migration, fluent-migrator, roundhouse

I want to know if I can have one SQL file per migration.

We are trying to use it with RoundhousE, but RoundhousE will stop if a SQL file already ran is ever altered.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the output command you are using to generate the sql from FM?

Comment: I think I need a bit more info on why you want to alter the sql file? Why would you want to change the file after deploying the change to your database schema? FluentMigrator allows you to rollback your change but you would not go back and change an already deployed migration. So more background info, please.

Comment: @DanielLee - RoundhousE (Chuck Norris FW) will throw an error if the script is ever modified. FluentMigrator outputs only to one file, and RH checks the hash of that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by forking FM and adding a `DirectoryAnnouncer` that then outputs one file per migration (named after the migration #).

Comment: Any chance you could send in a pull request? Sounds like a nice feature to have.